# Unity - Outline each pixel on a texture

Tags: unity

So I have a 16x16 sprite. I would like to make each pixel on the sprite to have a border/outline so you can distinguish each pixel from another, like shown in the picture below (ignore the colored boxes). How would I do so? Please note, I will be coloring those pixels, so those borders should be gone when colored

[image]

Comment: Are these literally pixels or cells? The pixel is the fundamental unit for computer graphics; you can't outline adjacent pixels without filling the region entirely with the outline color. Can you restate the question?

Comment: They are pixels yes